# ESPER: How to use EPL statement to detect 2 or more sequential events?

Tags: esper

I am so new to this technology and I need to be able to detect events happening in exact sequential order. For example:
a -> b -> c to output an event based on these events
a -> b -> d -> …-> c will not output an event based on these events since a, b, and c event are not in sequential order.

Is that possible with ESPER EPL statement.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options

1. Reorder the stream waiting for late-arriving events. Esper can do this for you with [time_order](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.3.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#view-time-order).
2. Use a EPL join instead; in a join the events can arrive in any order

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look.